# Using while loop to validate password in Java

Tags: java, validation, while-loop, passwords

The prompt is to have a user input a password and the password must be at least 8 characters with no white spaces, must have one upper case letter, and must have one digit. It has to use a while loop. If the password conforms it should output "password ok" or otherwise say "try again"

Anyone know what to do for this?
All I can pretty much do is the scanner and user input

Comment: What you have tried ? Post your code.

Comment: Good luck with someone who will take care of spoon-feeding !!!

Comment: This is not a place for your Assignment solution...

Answer (score 0):

Use 2 boolean flags. One each for checking presence of *digit*, *uppercase* letter. Your condition could go like :

```
//loop start
{
if(string.charAt(i)==space){
print "not valid"
return false;
}
// check for capital letter here and set flag to true if it is found.
// check digit here and set that flag to true if found.
}//loop end

// outside the loop make these checks

if(string.length>8 && isCapitalFound && isDigitFound)
//print "valid"
return true
```

Comment: Isn't the idea that it keeps looping until the user enters a valid password? If you return true/false while inside the loop, won't that cause the loop to end prematurely and not keep resetting even if the password is invalid?

Comment: @Fodder - the program is just an outline.. didn't have time to go into the details.

Answer (score 0):

I made your home work for you:

```
boolean noWhite = false;
boolean oneUppercase = false;
boolean oneDigit = false;
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
String pass = "";
while (!noWhite || !oneUppercase || !oneDigit || pass.length() < 8) {
  System.out.print("new pass: ");
  pass = scan.next();
  noWhite = !pass.contains(" ");
  oneUppercase = !pass.equals(pass.toLowerCase());
  oneDigit = pass.matches(".*\\d.*");
}
System.out.println("OK");
```